# Join two tables with columns of one corresponding to rows of another

Tags: sql, database, join, sqlite

I have a table (call it **Table1**) in which i store some info about movies:

```
| id | Title | Producer | Released | Actors |
---------------------------------------------
| 1  | Blah1 | Blah1    | Blah1    | Blah1  |
| 2  | Blah2 | Blah2    | Blah2    | Blah2  |
| 3  | Blah3 | Blah3    | Blah3    | Blah3  |
|... | ...   | ...      | ...      | ...    |
```

There is no issue with that table, everything is fine here.

The issue is with another table (**Table2**). I have a script that runs once a day and checks movie rankings from a movie website. So I want to record what rankings all of the movies from Table1 have each day. So I came up with a table that looks like this:

```
| id | Date       | Movie1 | Movie2 | Movie3 | ... |
----------------------------------------------------
| 1  | Aug 1 2014 | 7.1    | 4.3    | 9.6    | ... |
| 2  | Aug 2 2014 | 7.2    | 4.2    | 9.4    | ... |
|... | ...        | ...    | ...    | ...    | ... |
```

The script runs once a day, so there is a single row of rankings created each day. *Movie1* corresponds to movie info row with *id*=1 from Table1, *Movie2* similarly corresponds to movie info row with *id*=2 from Table1, and so on.

---

**First question**: How can I join an entire Table1 with a singe row from Table2? (rows from Table1 correspond to *MovieN* columns in Table2).

The result would be an entire Table1 with additional Ranking column with values from the Table2 row. For example, joining Table1 with Table2's row on *Date*=Aug 2 2014:

```
| id | Title | Producer | Released | Actors | Ranking |
-------------------------------------------------------
| 1  | Blah1 | Blah1    | Blah1    | Blah1  | 7.2     |
| 2  | Blah2 | Blah2    | Blah2    | Blah2  | 4.2     |
| 3  | Blah3 | Blah3    | Blah3    | Blah3  | 9.4     |
|... | ...   | ...      | ...      | ...    | ...     |
```

**Second question**: How to do the same from the first question, but join Table1 with a row that is a difference of two Table2 rows (row2-row1), where row1: *Date*=Aug 1 2014 and row2: *Date*=Aug 2 2014. i.e.:

```
| id | Title | Producer | Released | Actors | Ranking |
-------------------------------------------------------
| 1  | Blah1 | Blah1    | Blah1    | Blah1  | 0.1     | <-- (7.2 - 7.1)
| 2  | Blah2 | Blah2    | Blah2    | Blah2  | -0.1    | <-- (4.2 - 4.3)
| 3  | Blah3 | Blah3    | Blah3    | Blah3  | -0.2    | <-- (9.4 - 9.6)
|... | ...   | ...      | ...      | ...    | ...     |
```

**Third question**: Every day I'm going to add a few new movies into Table1. If I add a new movie in Table1, I will have to insert a corresponding new column into Table2. It's generally done through *ALTER* SQL command, but how efficient/good design is it?

---

Also, I'm new to SQL databases, so If my db design is bad, please suggest a better one. Just note that what I will use that db for is querying ranking change of ALL movies between Date1 and Date2, just like in the second question, so it kind of makes sense to have a single row per day, so that I could query just 2 rows (one for Date1, another for Date2) and subtract them from each other to get the change in ranking for each movie during Date1-Date2 period of time.

Comment: @frank-n-stein Didn't know *insert* inserts columns too.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to skip to question 3 first because the design makes questions 1 & 2 unecessarily complex.

Create the following tables

```
Producers (id,Producer)
Actors (id,Actor)
Movies (id,Title,Released,producer_id)
Movie_Actors (movie_id,actor_id)
Movie_Rankings (id,movie_id,ranking_date,ranking)
```

Now you can approach question 1 the following way

```
SELECT id,Title,Released,Producer,ranking,
    group_concat(Actor) Actors
FROM Movies m
JOIN Producers p ON m.producer_id = p.id
JOIN Movie_Actors ma ON ma.movie_id = a.id
JOIN Actors a ON a.id = ma.actor_id
JOIN Movie_Rankings mr ON m.id = mr.movie_id 
    AND mr.ranking_date = '2014-08-02'
GROUP BY m.id
```

And question 2

```
SELECT id,Title,Released,Producer, 
    (mr.ranking - mr2.ranking), group_concat(Actor) Actors
FROM Movies m
JOIN Producers p ON m.producer_id = p.id
JOIN Movie_Actors ma ON ma.movie_id = a.id
JOIN Actors a ON a.id = ma.actor_id
JOIN Movie_Rankings mr ON m.id = mr.movie_id 
    AND mr.ranking_date = '2014-08-02'
JOIN Movie_Rankings mr2 ON m.id = mr2.movie_id 
    AND mr2.ranking_date = '2014-08-01'
GROUP BY m.id
```